# C string not being filled in function call

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm attempting to fill a few strings using a function, but the strings don't seem to be getting filled properly. The print statement is just 4 empty lines. BUT if I un-comment the char ** pls line, it prints all three strings properly even if I never use the variable pls anywhere. It also runs properly in debug mode without the pls variable existing. I'm not entirely sure what I did that it isn't happy about.

```
char * dataFile = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char));
//char ** pls = &dataFile;
char * queryFile = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char));
char * outFile = (char *) calloc(64, sizeof(char));
for(i = 1; i <argc; ++i)
{
    char command[3];
    char * iterator = argv[i];
    command[0] = *iterator;
    ++iterator;
    command[1] = *iterator;
    ++iterator;
    command[2] = *iterator;

    if(strcmp(command, "df=") == 0)
        determineFileString(iterator, &dataFile);
    else if(strcmp(command, "if=") == 0)
        determineFileString(iterator, &queryFile);
    else if(strcmp(command, "of=") == 0) 
        determineFileString(iterator, &outFile);
}
printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", dataFile, queryFile, outFile);

void determineFileString(char * iterator, char ** file)
{
    char * p = *file;
    ++iterator;
    while(*iterator != '\0')
    {
        *p = *iterator;
        ++p;
        ++iterator;
    }
    *p = '\0';
}
```

Comment: "it prints all three strings properly even if I never use the variable pls anywhere" smells like undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no need to cast calloc in C, its return type is void*. Any way come back with a code wich actually does compile to see how the program works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `strcmp` but the first operand does not point to a string.  A string is defined as some characters followed by a null terminator.

Your code will also cause undefined behaviour if an `argv[i]` string is shorter than 2 characters, because you always copy 3 characters out of it.

To fix this, either make `command` bigger and put a null terminator on the end, or use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`. (But be careful with `memcmp` as it also causes UB if both objects are not at least as big as the size).

Here is a possible fix:

```
for(i = 1; i <argc; ++i)
{
    if ( strlen(argv[i]) < 3 )
         continue;

    if ( memcmp(argv[i], "df=", 3) == 0 )
        determineFileString(argv[i] + 3, &dataFile);

    else if    // etc.
}
```

BTW, the `determineFileString` function does not do any buffer size checking (it could buffer overflow). I'd suggest redesigning this function; perhaps it could do a length check and call `realloc` inside the function.